# KDB - run a function where the function name and parameters are passed in as a string

Tags: kdb

I am putting together a process that queries a KDB session and returns various bits of data to the front end.
The front end passes a parameter to the KDB session which is a table name that comes in as a string – e.g. `"table"`, where `table` is a table in the KDB session

I can run some simple KDB functions on the underlying table referred to, for example:

```
count `$"table"
cols `$"table"
```

In other circumstances, the front end passes a string to the KDB session which specifies a function and a parameter which, when run, returns a table equivalent to `table` above – e.g. `"function parameter"`
I want to run the same simple functions on the table that is returned by running `function parameter`

The following do not return the output equivalent to `count table` and `cols table` respectively:

```
count `$"function parameter"
cols `$"function parameter"
```

What is the best way to get the count and cols from the table implied by the string `"function parameter"`

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example, `cols` is able to take either the table or the name of the table as a symbol as an argument, which is why it returns the column names as expected. `count` cannot take the name of the table as an argument so will return 1 since there is only a single symbol element.

`"function parameter"` has been cast to a symbol `` `function parameter `` and there is no table with this name and so passing this as an argument to `cols` will throw an error, while passing this to `count` will return 1 for the same reasons as before.

You might be interested in using the `value` function with a string argument and there is documentation on it here: http://code.kx.com/q/ref/metadata/#value.

It will evaluate the string argument as if it had been typed into the command prompt. Using `value "table"` will return the `table` variable and `value "function parameter"` will run function with the parameter which will also a table.

These can then be passed into your simple functions using `count value "function parameter"` or `count value "table"` to return the desired output.

Hope this is useful,

Mark

Comment: Thank you - very helpful

Answer (score 2):

`{simple function} eval eval parse "x"` should work for both.

Answer (score 1):

```
count get["function parameter"]
cols get["function parameter"]
```

should work, and doesn't require you to cast the parameter from character-array to symbol.